# C++ Linker Error LNK2019

Tags: c++, linker, lnk2019

I'm still kind of new to C++ and don't know why I'm getting these linker errors while trying trying to call these functions in another class.

The errors are:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: float __thiscall Star::getMass(void)" (?getMass@Star@@QAEMXZ) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall Projectile::Update(class Star * const,int)" (?Update@Projectile@@QAEXQAVStar@@H@Z)

error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: float __thiscall Star::getX(void)" (?getX@Star@@QAEMXZ) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall Projectile::Update(class Star * const,int)" (?Update@Projectile@@QAEXQAVStar@@H@Z)

error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: float __thiscall Star::getY(void)" (?getY@Star@@QAEMXZ) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall Projectile::Update(class Star * const,int)" (?Update@Projectile@@QAEXQAVStar@@H@Z)
```

Projectile.cpp:

```
#include <hge.h>
#include "Projectile.h"
#include "Physics.h"
#include "Star.h"
#include <math.h>

Projectile::Projectile(float xV, float yV, float x, float y, float m, HTEXTURE tex)
{
    xVel = xV;
    yVel = yV;
    xPos = x;
    yPos = y;
    mass = m;
    quad.tex = tex;
}

void Projectile::Update(Star stars[], int length)
{
    for(int i = 0; i<length; ++i)
    {
        float force = Physics::calcGravityForce(mass, stars[i].getMass(), Physics::calcDist(xPos, yPos, stars[i].getX(), stars[i].getY()));
        Accelerate(force, stars[i].getX() - xPos, stars[i].getY() - yPos);
    }
}

void Projectile::Accelerate(float force, float x, float y)
{
    float c = sqrt((x * x) + (y * y));
    xVel += x/c;
    yVel += y/c;
}
```

Star is defined in Star.h here:

```
#ifndef STAR_H
#define STAR_H

#include <hge.h>

class Star
{
private:
    float mass, radius, x, y;
    hgeQuad quad;

public:
    Star(float m, float r, float X, float Y, HTEXTURE);
    float getMass();
    float getRadius();
    float getX();
    float getY();
    Star() {}
};

#endif
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several functions declared in the `Star` class:

```
Star(float m, float r, float X, float Y, HTEXTURE);
float getMass();
float getRadius();
float getX();
float getY();
```

And you are trying to use some of them without providing a *definition*, that is to say, the body of the function, which is why you're getting those linker errors.

Add a new .cpp file to your project named `Star.cpp` (the name doesn't matter though) and add the definitions of the functions for the `Star` class, like you've done for the `Projectile` class. (You could just add them to any .cpp file in your project, like `Projectile.cpp`, but if you have a separate header file, it's good to have a seperate .cpp file too.)

Or if you don't want to have another cpp file in your project, you can put the bodies of the functions inside the class itself:

```
class Star
{
private:
    float mass, radius, x, y;
    hgeQuad quad;

public:
    Star(float m, float r, float X, float Y, HTEXTURE);
    float getMass() { return mass; }
    float getRadius() { return radius; }
    float getX() { return x; }
    float getY() { return y; }
    Star() {}
};
```

That style is common for small "getter" functions like `getMass`, `getRadius`, etc. which just return a member variable.

---

Though it's not directly related to your question, I should point out a few things:

1. Make all your "getter" functions (like `getMass` etc) `const` (so that they can be used on `const Star` objects) by putting the word `const` after the parameters (the `()` in this case) like this: `float getMass() const { return mass; }`
2. Because you have member variables in the `Star` class, you should set them to some sensible default value in the constructor which takes no parameters,

like this:

```
Star() : mass(0), radius(0), x(0), y(0) {}
```

Which will set `mass`, `radius`, `x` and `y` to `0`. (This unusual syntax is called an *initialiser list*. You can read about them [here](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/initialization-lists-c++.html).)

You can even do this without a seperate constructor by using default arguments:

```
Star(float m = 0, float r = 0, float X = 0, float Y = 0, HTEXTURE = 0);
```

Comment: OH wow I'm stupid I totally forgot to define those. I'm sorry, thanks for the help!

Comment: @Nate if this answer answered your question, don't forget to mark it as the answer by clicking the check mark to the left side of it.